# Angularjs: Best way to deal with foreign keys in items data

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have files and folders. Folders contain files.

The JSON that I get from the server looks like this:

```
folder: {id: 5, name: "my stuff" }
file: {id: 3, name: "my file", folderId: 5}
file: {id: 5, name: "my file 2", folderId: 5}
```

Whats the best way to build a Folder - File structure? Nest the files in the folder like:

```
{id: 5, name: "my stuff" files: [
    {id: 3, name: "my file", folderId: 5},
    {id: 5, name: "my file 2", folderId: 5}
]},
{id: 6, name: "other things" files: [
    {id: 1, name: "my file", folderId: 6},
    {id: 2, name: "my file 2", folderId: 6}
]}
```

Or use a filter that only returns the files that belong to a folder id? Like:

```
<li ng-repeat="folder in folders">
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="file in files | fileInFolder:folder.id"></li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

**Files can be moved to different folders!**

Comment: The filtering option was too slow because i iterated over all items when only trying to access a single one. Ive built some caches that have the correct filtering of objects that i need and now it works like a charm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "best way" is always whatever way it's easiest to maintain. For me, personally, I like option 2 (the filters) because it fits the data you're getting. However, option 1 (the json structure) is a much better representation of the data, IMO. If you're stuck with that data structure, then I guess option 2 would be my choice.

... but I don't know anything about your application structure. Is this persisted to the database? When is it persisted? Instantaneously? Or only after a save has been called?  Lots of factors will play into what structure will work best for you and be more maintainable for your particular solution.

Comment: This will be nstantaneously persisted to the database. Also, I can create now folders and files. That should also be saved immediately.

Comment: +1 to filter option.  You don't want to have restructure your data constantly